# How to instantiate vivado ip integrator cores using VHDL-93 syntax?

Tags: vhdl, vivado

How to instantiate an IP core created with  Xilinx's Vivado IP integrator in vhdl using vhdl-93 "entity libray" syntax instead of using components?

```
    --Attempting to instantiate Vivado 
    --IP integator core using 
    --VHDL-93 entity syntax
    clk_wiz_1: entity work.clk_wiz_1(
        clkin => clkin,
        clkout => clkout,
        locked => locked,
        reset => reset
    );
    --result: ERROR: can't find it in library
   -- work...

   --however, when i go back to the 
   -- old VHDL syntax of putting a 
   -- redundant component in the file
   -- it works...
```

I really prefer to avoid using old style vhdl "components" for every vivado IP core i want to instantiate...

how to instantiate vivado ip cores using VHDL-93 entity syntax?

Comment: I found that only the top module has to be the "old fashion" style. I am using Verilog and I use system Verilog for all modules, except the top one. Having said that: I only use 'add module' where I know that rule applies. I don't know the rules for IP.

Comment: Xilinx puts everything in a xil_defaultlib library by default. So try using that

Comment: As Tricky alludes and the error message snippet indicates there isn't a primary unit in the library work named clk_wiz_1.

Comment: A component declaration provides a virtual component that is bound during elaboration as is a component instantiation using the reserved word **entity**. The difference is the latter requires the entity declaration be visible during analysis. Component binding that fails during elaboration does not result in an error necessarily.

Comment: Components are *not* "old-style"; they're the right way to do hierarchy. Just because direct instantation came with the '93 LRM doesn't make them better. They are not a replacement for components.

Comment: @EML Exactly.  In my younger days, we used direct instantation everywhere.  The ability to swap sub-components and tweak generics using configurations is very powerful, and is possible only with "old-style" components.  We've now switched back to component use.